# Gmaps.map.callback not working after calling replaceMarkers using Gmaps4rails gem?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmaps4rails

I am using Gmaps4rails and have successfully got quite a bit working, but I am a bit stumped.  Probably due to my novice JS skills.   I have been trying to follow examples in various questions but I am not sure where I am going wrong.

When my map loads the Gmaps.map.callback is working fine, Map is loaded, I click on a marker and the listener event fires.

In my view:

```
<% content_for :scripts do %>
<script type="text/javascript">
Gmaps.map.callback = function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < Gmaps.map.markers.length; i++){
    marker = Gmaps.map.markers[i];
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker.serviceObject, 'click', 
      (function(marker){
        return function(){      
      alert(marker.id);
        }
      })(marker)
   )
 }
}
</script>
<% end %>
```

This will alert with the marker id from the json created in the controller.

I then have a search function that updates the location of the map and replaces the markers. This is getting called in an ajax call.  So in the controllers .js.erb I do this:

```
Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers(<%= raw @json %>);
```

Everything seems fine, my map is loaded with the new markers, but the even listener does not work on the markers.

So my question is, how do I get these new markers to have the Listener for the click event. Do I need to reset the callback somehow?  I think it has to run before the map gets loaded but in this case I am not reloading the map, just replacing the markers.

Comment: the callback is not meant to be triggered each time markers are added. Simply

Comment: @apneadiving not sure if something got cut off in your response.  How do I get the listener event to be attached to the markers after calling replaceMarkers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract your method to reuse it:

```
Gmaps.map.listen_to_markers = function(markers){
  for(var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
    marker = markers[i];
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker.serviceObject, 'click', 
      (function(marker){
        return function(){      
          alert(marker.id);
        }
      })(marker)
   )
 }
}

Gmaps.map.callback = function(){
  Gmaps.map.listen_to_markers(Gmaps.map.markers);
}
```

And whenever you replace markers:

```
var new_markers = <%= raw @json %>;
Gmaps.map.replaceMarkers(new_markers);
Gmaps.map.listen_to_markers(new_markers);
```

Comment: This works great. If I had more reputation I would up-vote this for you as well. I was trying something similar to this, but couldn't get it right.  This also gives me more insight into how this works.   Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Discard "content_for", "Gmaps.map.callback" etc.
Keep `buildMap(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>)` in your view file.

In your coffeescript file, insert your own work after the line of code `handler.fitMapToBounds();`

For example, click on an item of navigation bar and trigger click function on specific marker to open infowindow.

In .html.erb file,

```
a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mapEventName" id="<%= i %>"><%= event.event_name %>
```

In .js.coffee file,

```
$(".mapEventName").on "click", ->
  i = $(this).attr("id")
  marker = markers[i]
  alert(marker.getServiceObject().getPosition().toString())
  google.maps.event.trigger marker.getServiceObject(), "click"

> "
```